# Problem querying an HTML file using HTMLEditorKit in Java

Tags: java, html, parsing

My HTML contains tags of the following form:

```
<div class="author"><a href="/user/1" title="View user profile.">Apple</a> - October 22, 2009 - 01:07</div>
```

I'd like to extract the date, "October 22, 2009 - 01:07" in this example, from each tag

I've implemented javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit.ParserCallback as follows:

```
class HTMLParseListerInner extends HTMLEditorKit.ParserCallback {   
    private ArrayList<String> foundDates = new ArrayList<String>();
    private boolean isDivLink = false;

    public void handleText(char[] data, int pos) {
        if(isDivLink)
            foundDates.add(new String(data)); // Extracts "Apple" instead of the date.
    }

    public void handleStartTag(HTML.Tag t, MutableAttributeSet a, int pos) {       
        String divValue = (String)a.getAttribute(HTML.Attribute.CLASS);
        if (t.toString() == "div" && divValue != null && divValue.equals("author"))
            isDivLink = true;
    }
}
```

However, the above parser returns "Apple" which is inside a hyperlink within the  tag. How can I fix the parser to extract the date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `handleEndTag` and check for `"a"`?

However, this HTML parser is from the early 90's and these methods are not well specified.

Comment: And whilst I think about it, it generally isn't a good idea to use `==` on `String`s.

Comment: I searched for html parsers in Java and this seems like a popular one. If you know any other easy to use parsers I'll appreciate if you could introduce them.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.parser.*;

public class ParserCallbackDiv extends HTMLEditorKit.ParserCallback
{
    private boolean isDivLink = false;
    private String divText;

    public void handleEndTag(HTML.Tag tag, int pos)
    {
        if (tag.equals(HTML.Tag.DIV))
        {
            System.out.println( divText );
            isDivLink = false;
        }
    }

    public void handleStartTag(HTML.Tag tag, MutableAttributeSet a, int pos)
    {
        if (tag.equals(HTML.Tag.DIV))
        {
            String divValue = (String)a.getAttribute(HTML.Attribute.CLASS);

            if ("author".equals(divValue))
                isDivLink = true;
        }
    }

    public void handleText(char[] data, int pos)
    {
        divText = new String(data);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws IOException
    {
        String file = "<div class=\"author\"><a href=\"/user/1\"" +
            "title=\"View user profile.\">Apple</a> - October 22, 2009 - 01:07</div>";
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(file);

        ParserCallbackDiv parser = new ParserCallbackDiv();

        try
        {
            new ParserDelegator().parse(reader, parser, true);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```